# How to flush out subscribed messages?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is it possible to remove messages stored in subscriber queue. For example if I start a new iteration I would want to remove all the message stored in queue which are from previous iteration. Is it possible to do this using any message filters like cache or time sequencer??

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/71737/how-to-flush-out-subscribed-messages??/) by [ayush_dewan](https://answers.ros.org/users/2268/ayush_dewan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1610 on 2013-08-07

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you want to empty the queue you can simply have your callback short circuit and not do anything. If you want to do more advanced queuing it is recommended to build your own queue internally so that you have full control.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2014-01-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0